# using dump to dump output of a search query as a json file does not work

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have been trying to dump the result of an elasticsearch query into a file but python only shows me an error message. Here is my code:

```
import json
count=0
keyword_array = []

with open('localFile','r') as my_keywordfile:
for keyword in my_keywordfile.readlines():
    keyword_array.append(keyword.strip().strip("'"))
with open( 'localFile', 'wb') as f:
    for x in keyword_array:
        doc = {
                        "query": {                                
                                "multi_match": {
                                    "query": x,
                                    "type": "phrase",
                                    "fields":"_all",    

                                }
                        }

              }

        res = es.search(index='dbgap_062617', body=doc)
        json.dump(res, f)
```

f is the file that it is opened in "w" mode, and res is the output of the search query.
Here is the error that I see;

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Then, I changed the code with

```
json.dump(''.join(res), f)
```

and this:

```
json.dump(str(res), f)
```

But again, the same error! Does anyone know why this is happening? If I use dumps it works, but I have heard that we should not use dumps!

Comment: Show us a [mcve]. We can't see where `res` is coming from or how you opened the file.

Comment: @user2357112 edited the code.

Comment: That's opened in `wb` mode, not `w` mode.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks it worked. However, when I wanted to validate the json file on "https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer#" it showed: JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate. Here is the code I used: everything the same except used this one: with open('localfile','w',encoding="utf-8") as f:   and json.dump(res, f, ensure_ascii=False). Any idea why is it like this? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to @user2357112. "That's opened in wb mode, not w mode." Alos, the reason that I got JSON String is valid but JSON Data is not accurate on "codebeautify.org/jsonviewer#" was that apparently these websites allow you to only pase a limited number of characters and my file was not completely loaded.